# Save values on input change in shiny R

Tags: r, shiny

I have the code below. I can check whether the input values changed and warn user to recalculate the values. However, I can not figure out, how to track particular changes and save all of them into a log-file without clicking any action button. Thank you for your comments, Martin.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- fluidPage(
  inputPanel(
    #arbritray inputs
    sliderInput("in1", label = "Input 1", value=1,min=0,max=5),
    sliderInput("in2", label = "Input 2", value=2,min=0,max=5),
    sliderInput("in3", label = "Input 3", value=3,min=0,max=5),
    actionButton("StartCalculation","Calculate")
  ),
  textOutput("answer"),
  textOutput("status")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  status <- reactiveVal()
  out <- eventReactive(input$StartCalculation,{
    status("up to date")
    Sys.sleep(2) #simulate long computation
    input$in1+input$in2+input$in3
  })
 
  observeEvent({list(input$in1,input$in2,input$in3)},
               {status("Needs recalculation")})

  output$answer <- renderText({out()})

  output$status <- renderText({status()})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I think we'll need a little more information about how you're hoping this log file would work. Is this a purely internal app, so it could `observeEvent` input$in1 and writeLines each time? Or will you be hosting it somewhere and would instead find it most useful to write it out to the logs with a `print` statement inside your already existing `observeEvent` block so that info will show up in error logs? Or something else entirely?

Answer (score 1):

While it is not exactly clear what you are trying to achieve, saving all the changes to the input variables can be performed by defining a `reactiveValues` object as shown below.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  inputPanel(
    #arbritray inputs
    sliderInput("in1", label = "Input 1", value=1,min=0,max=5),
    sliderInput("in2", label = "Input 2", value=2,min=0,max=5),
    sliderInput("in3", label = "Input 3", value=3,min=0,max=5),
    actionButton("StartCalculation","Calculate")
  ),
  textOutput("answer"),
  textOutput("status"),
  DTOutput("all")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  status <- reactiveVal()
  allvalues <- reactiveValues(data=NULL)
  out <- eventReactive(input$StartCalculation,{
    status("up to date")
    Sys.sleep(2) #simulate long computation
    input$in1+input$in2+input$in3
  })
  
  observeEvent(list(input$in1,input$in2,input$in3), {
    allvalues$data <- rbind(allvalues$data,data.frame(a=input$in1,b=input$in2,c=input$in3))
    status("Needs recalculation")
  })
  
  output$answer <- renderText({out()})
  output$all <- renderDT({allvalues$data})
  output$status <- renderText({status()})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```